# Filter by type matching in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter, types, predicate

I am trying to filter based on a type in Typescript.

Essentially, I have 4 states, but on one screen I only want to display 3 of the options.

```
export const ADOPTION_LABELS: Record<
  Collections.AdoptionReasons,
  string
> = {
  [AdoptionReasons.CuteDog]:
    'It was a cute dog',
  [AdoptionReasons.Behavior]:
    'Behaved well',
  [AdoptionReasons.ManuallyCreated]: 'Manually created',
  [AdoptionReasons.Other]: 'Other',
};
```

On the screen, I show radio buttons where the user can select any reason. However, I want to filter out ManuallyCreated.

```
     {Object.entries(ADOPTION_LABELS).map(([reason, label]) => (
          <FormControlLabel
            key={reason}
            classes={{
              label: classes.radioButtonLabel,
            }}
            control={<Radio value={reason} />}
            label={label}
          />
        ))}
```

To do this, I created a new type:

```
export type SupportedAdoptionReasons = Exclude<
  Collections.AdoptionReasons,
  Collections.AdoptionReasons.ManuallyCreated
>;
```

I've been looking up type predicates, so have been trying to do something like

```
const isSupportedAdoptionReason = (label: string): label is SupportedAdoptionReasons => typeof label === instanceof SupportedAdoptionReasons)
```

and

```
  const supportedAdoptionReasonLabels = Object.entries(ADOPTION_LABELS).filter(isSupportedAdoptionReason)
```

I feel like I'm getting really stuck when it comes to the type predicate. Can someone illuminate the best way forward?

Answer (score 0):

Your type predicate is correct, but your `isSupportedAdoptionReason` function is wrong. `instanceof` returns a boolean and `typeof label` is always string, so the function will always return false. You also can't use a type as the `instanceof` operator, types are removed on build time and are not valid JavaScript objects.

Try this:

```
enum Test {
    ONE = "one",
    TWO = "two"
}

// Type predicate isn't even needed, but good to have if you want
const filterTest = (x: string, label: Test): x is Test => x !== label; 

const testObj = {
    [Test.ONE]: "hello",
    [Test.TWO]: "world"
}

// returns [[[Test.ONE], "hello"]]
const filtered = Object.entries(testObj).filter(x => filterTest(x[0], Test.TWO))
```